# getting method name from method invocation? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a class Foo:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
  end

  def baz
  end
 end
```

Possible to create a method of object called "method_name" that returns the name of the method being invoked?

```
>>Foo.bar.method_name
"Foo.bar"
```

or if invoked on an instance?

```
>>f=Foo.new
#<Foo:0x3bdc138>
>>f.baz.method_name
"Foo.baz"
```

I know is possible to use the method method to do something similar, but that requires typing a symbol as a parameter.  I actually want to avoid doing that because the point is to enable code completion so you don't have to worry retyping the method name.

Comment: As you write it, you will invoke this method_name call on the value being returned by Foo.bar, so this will never work...

Answer (score 0):

In the way you wrote it this is not possible, as your `method_name` method would have to be defined very hi up in the hierarchy, probably `Object` in order to be called on all possible *results* of methods. The trouble with of your `method_name` method is, that it could not operate *within* the method you call, it could only operate *on* the *result* of the method you called, this will usually have no information about the name of the method it came from (except if these methods where explicitly written to return this information that is).

*Within* a method you have access to the `__callee__` method or the `__method__` method which return the name of method where they are called in. This would only differ from what the method is called in `def …` if the method has been aliased.

*Within* a method you can also access your call stack through the `caller` method (which yields an array). However, this will still not quite permit you to do what you like, as you will not be operating *within* the `bar` and `baz` methods as you call `method_name` on the *result* of these methods (which at the time of this writing are both nil). The results do not have any info on the call stack anymore.